# Alpacajs form data not submitting if user does not tab off textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, blur, alpacajs

I am having an issue with alpacajs form not submitting data from a textbox if the user does not tab off the textbox before clicking the submit button, if the user has 5 fields to fill out all but the last one is included in the json results.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordian" role="tablist">
    <div class="panel-placeholder"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<script id="panel-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each panels}}
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{panelId}}">
                        {{title}}
                    </a>
                </h4>
                </div>
                    <div id="{{panelId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{#each sections}}
                <div id={{formId}}></div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

and the js code

```
function onData(formData) {
    var friendlyData = "";

    // Grab the template script
    var templateScript = $("#panel-template").html();

    // Compile the template
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);

    var compiledHtml = compiledTemplate(formData);

    // Add the compiled html to the page
    $('.panel-placeholder').html(compiledHtml);

    //submit all data
    $("[type='submit']").click(function () {

        var postData = {
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            friendlyData: friendlyData,
            storeData: storeData,
            origUrl: origUrl
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + "submit/",
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data was saved");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Any help with this would be great, I have not been able to find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a form and listening for submit instead?

Comment: I tried in a form, the blur event just doesn't fire right away, as long as I click anywhere else other than the submit button the json is updated.